# SQL Server - import XML fields from multiple levels

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm wanting to select the XML hierarchy value for Chart Name into the first column for all Filter values under that Chart.

I've used the method below but ChartName returns a NULL.  I suspect I will need to do a subquery

```
DECLARE @input XML = 
'<Report>
    <DataSets>
    </DataSets>
    <ReportSections>
      <ReportSection>
        <ReportItems>
          <Chart Name="Hub1">
            <Filters>
                <Filter>
                  <Expression>Fields!Hub.Value</Expression>
                  <Operator>Like</Operator>
                  <Values>
                    <Value>Central</Value>
                  </Values>
                </Filter>
                <Filter>
                    <Expression>Fields!ADP_Hrs.Value</Expression>
                    <Operator>NotEqual</Operator>
                    <Values>
                      <Value DataType="Float">0</Value>
                    </Values>
                </Filter>
                <Filter>
                    <Expression>Fields!TL.Value</Expression>
                    <Operator>Equal</Operator>
                    <Values>
                      <Value DataType="Integer">1</Value>
                    </Values>
                </Filter>
            </Filters>
          </Chart>  
        </ReportItems>
      </ReportSection>
    </ReportSections>
</Report>'

SELECT
    [Tbl].[Col].value('Chart [4]', 'varchar(50)') as ChartName,
    [Tbl].[Col].value('Expression [1]', 'varchar(50)') as Expression,
    [Tbl].[Col].value(' Operator [1]', 'varchar(50)') as 'Operator',
    [Tbl].[Col].value(' Values [1]', 'varchar(50)') as 'Value'
FROM 
    @input.nodes('Report/ReportSections/ReportSection/ReportItems/Chart/Filters/Filter') as [Tbl]([Col])
```

Expected output:

```
ChartName  Expression              Operator    Value
------------------------------------------------------
Hub1       Fields!Hub.Value        Like        Central
Hub1       Fields!ADP_Hrs.Value    NotEqual    0 
Hub1       Fields!TL.Value         Equal       1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Chart` is not within the `Filter` element, so it can't find it unless you walk backwards up the XML path, and then pull the `@Name` attribute of the `Chart` element:

```
SELECT
[Tbl].[Col].value('(../../@Name)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as ChartName,
[Tbl].[Col].value('Expression [1]', 'varchar(50)') as Expression,
[Tbl].[Col].value(' Operator [1]', 'varchar(50)') as 'Operator',
[Tbl].[Col].value(' Values [1]', 'varchar(50)') as 'Value'

FROM @input.nodes('Report/ReportSections/ReportSection/ReportItems/Chart/Filters/Filter') as [Tbl]([Col])
```

Which returns:

```
ChartName      Expression              Operator     Value
-------------- ----------------------- ------------ -------------
Hub1           Fields!Hub.Value        Like         Central
Hub1           Fields!ADP_Hrs.Value    NotEqual     0
Hub1           Fields!TL.Value         Equal        1
```

Comment: Thanks James and John, both work well, this gives me a good understanding of how to return results from up and down the heirarchy

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option

**Example**

```
Select ChartName    = lvl1.n.value('@Name'        ,'varchar(50)') 
      ,Expression   = lvl2.n.value('Expression[1]','varchar(50)') 
      ,Operator     = lvl2.n.value('Operator[1]'  ,'varchar(50)') 
      ,Value        = lvl2.n.value('Values[1]'    ,'varchar(50)') 
 From  @input.nodes('Report/ReportSections/ReportSection/ReportItems/*') lvl1(n)
 Cross Apply lvl1.n.nodes('Filters/Filter') lvl2(n)
```

**Returns**

```
ChartName   Expression              Operator    Value
Hub1        Fields!Hub.Value        Like        Central
Hub1        Fields!ADP_Hrs.Value    NotEqual    0
Hub1        Fields!TL.Value         Equal       1
```